# Type trait for extracting template parameter from nested type

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I need to get the template parameter from a nested type. Here is a simple example to show the type I need to extract.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T>
void function(T) {
    // T = 'struct A<int>::B'
    //
    // Here I want to get the template value type e.g. 'int' from T
    // so that this would print 'int'. How can this be done?        
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl; 
}

template<typename T>
struct A { 
    using B = struct { int f; };
};

int main() {
    function(A<int>::B{});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a `typedef` inside `B` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't extract this through simple deduction. Although `B` is a nested class of `A`, the types themselves are unrelated.

One option would be to "save" the type inside `B` and extract it later:

```
template<typename T>
struct A { 
    struct B { 
        using outer = T; 
        int f; 
    };
};
```

Then you just use `typename T::outer` to get the type:

```
template<typename T>
void function(T) {     
    std::cout << typeid(typename T::outer).name() << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: A nice and simple solution. I tried so many different things but did not think of this one. Thanks!